# Is there a reason my javascript function is being ran without being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am running a script to verify a users age. The function being used to check for the cookie works the first time a user goes to a page, and redirects to the home page where the age verification lives if they do not have the requested cookie.

Once this happens, the cookie is actually being created on the redirect at which point the user can go to any subpage of the site. Could anyone point out why this could be happening?

```
    //Setting The Value Of The Cookie
    var this_cookies_value = "_addMeToTheBrowser_";

    //Checks page on load to see if this_cookies_value already exists
    function checkForOurCookiesValue() {
    var allTheCookies = document.cookie;
    var _this_Host_Name_ = '"' + window.location.hostname + '"';
    var _this_Path_Name = window.location.pathname;

    console.log(allTheCookies);

    if(allTheCookies.includes(this_cookies_value) || _this_Path_Name == "/") {
    console.log("WORKING");
    } else {
    window.location.replace(_this_Host_Name_);
    };

    }
    checkForOurCookiesValue();


    //If cookie does not exist, this script will run once users age is verified correctly
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {

    if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    return true;
    }
    //Creating the cookie
    jQuery(".the_btn").on("click", createCookie("_my_domain_", this_cookies_value, 1));`enter code here`
```

Comment: You call the function in the last line of your code

Comment: You probably meant to write `jQuery(".the_btn").on("click", function(event) { createCookie("_my_domain_", this_cookies_value, 1); });`

Comment: `on('click', createCookie(...))` is not the same as `on('click', function(){ createCookie(...)})`

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks you guys for this. Issues is solved now. @bergi

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your function an anonymous (nameless) function in your last line.

## Your code

```
jQuery(".the_btn")
  .on(
    "click",
    createCookie("_my_domain_", this_cookies_value, 1)
  );
```

## Correct code

```
jQuery(".the_btn")
  .on(
    "click",
    function() {
      createCookie("_my_domain_", this_cookies_value, 1)
    }
  );
```

When your code is read by the browser it sees `createCookie()` as a function call it needs to run right away. If you put it inside an anonymous function, then it won't be called, rather another function will be created to be called later by the `click` event.

Considering you're using jQuery, I assume you need full browser support, and IE doesn't support ["fat arrow"](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) functions yet; however, if you don't need IE support, you can use the following code:

```
jQuery(".the_btn")
  .on(
    "click",
    () => createCookie("_my_domain_", this_cookies_value, 1)
  );
```

## Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/AnonymousSB/Lyn58bax/2/